# How do I unittest CGI.pm's file upload?

Tags: perl, cgi, mime

I have a CGI which gets a File uploaded and does something with it.

I would like a Unittest for the fileupload functionality

After reading http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=249917

I tried to adapt the code in CGI.pm's `t/upload.t`

```
{
%ENV = (
%ENV, 
      'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/data.cgi',
      'SERVER_NAME' => 'localhost',
      'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'TE, close',
      'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',
      'SCRIPT_URI' => 'http://localhost/data.cgi',
      'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '160',
      'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/var/www/cgi-bin/data.cgi',
      'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache/1.3.27 (Unix) ',
      'HTTP_TE' => 'deflate,gzip;q=0.3',
      'QUERY_STRING' => '',
      'REMOTE_PORT' => '1855',
      'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'libwww-perl/5.69',
      'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
      'REMOTE_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
      'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY',
      'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
      'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin',
      'REQUEST_URI' => '/data.cgi',
      'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
      'SCRIPT_URL' => '/data.cgi',
      'SERVER_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
      'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/var/www/html',
      'HTTP_HOST' => 'localhost'
    );

local *STDIN;
open STDIN, '<test.txt' or die 'argh';
binmode STDIN;

$cgi = new CGI;

run()
}
```

test.txt:

```
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hello_world"; filename="goodbye_world.txt"
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/plain

Goodbye World!
--xYzZY--
```

Now i get "400 Bad request (malformed multipart POST)" in cgi_error when i try to access the filehandle with

```
  our $cgi;

  sub run() {
  $cgi = new CGI unless $cgi;
  my $upload_fh =  $cgi->upload('upload');
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to include more of your modified unit test file, and possibly also some of the real code in the question. The `upload.t` file is for unit-testing CGI.pm, while you want to test your code that uses CGI. If you want to test the behavior of your program and trust that CGI does the right thing (that's what a unit-test is) then you can simply mock the CGI object.

Comment: CGI has its own tests. Write your code in a way that it can be tested separately.

Comment: thanks simbabque. I added the code for the Environment. Indeed before my CONTENT_LENGTH was wrong. But now cgi_error is set to 400

Comment: What is in `run()`? Is that part of your regular program? In order for this to work, you need to inject the `$cgi` object into your regular code somehow. Also the `local *STDIN` without a narrow scope doesn't really make much sense as it's scoped until the end of the file like that.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough context. the injection works, there already about 50 tests.